# Nonparametric for lmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, nonparametric

I am trying to fit a model based on the `df` dataframe, where I want to be able to compare all of the levels between/within the treatments (`treatment * level`). I will probably have to opt for a non parametric equivalent to `lmer` (I am not sure if this should be `glmer`?). I am looking for suggestions within library `lme4` but I am open to alternatives. The dataframe looks like this:

```
df <- structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CCF", "UN"), class = "factor"), level = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "F", "H", "L"
    ), class = "factor"), random = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1.6", "2", "3.2", "5", NA), class = "factor"), 
        continuous = c(72.7951770264767, 149.373765810534, 1.64153094886205, 
        54.6697408615215, 25.5801835808851, 1.45794117443253, 25.3660934894788, 
        91.2321704897132, 2.75353217433675, 44.1995276851725, 33.1854545470435, 
        5.36536076058866, 29.6807620242672, 80.6077496067764, 0.833434180091457, 
        13.6789475327185, 77.4930412025109, 3.65998714174906, 25.2848344605563, 
        136.632099849828, 2.56715261161435, 28.6733878840584, 66.800616194317, 
        1.37475468782539, 23.007491380183, 84.980285774607, 1.13569710795522, 
        33.8610875632139, 56.1234827517798, 1.32327007970416, 60.0843812879313, 
        43.4487832450889, 1.14942423621912, 53.6673704529947, 146.746167255051, 
        3.91593723271292, 27.0321687961004, 89.5925729244878, 1.47707078226047, 
        44.0523211310831, 115.087908243373, 1.94039630728038, 86.4074806697431, 
        43.3266206881612, 2.81456503996437, 66.868588961071, 229.797526052566, 
        1.07971524769264, 30.3390107111747, 116.680801084036, 1.67711446647817, 
        69.0961010697534, 78.5454363192614, 1.92137892126384, 53.5708546850303, 
        37.7175476710608, 1.96087397451467, 25.5166981770257, 37.3755071788757, 
        2.21602000526086, 10.3266195584378, 38.1458490762217, 2.7508022340832, 
        44.5864920143771, 8.45382647692274, 2.63204944520792, 87.5376946978593, 
        27.2354119098268, 3.38134648323956, 26.8815471706502, 14.5539972194568, 
        2.0556994322415, 27.4619977737491, 32.8546665896602, 2.66809379088059, 
        42.3815445857533, 21.3359802201685, 2.19167325121191, 53.3189825439001, 
        13.5708790223439, 2.22274607227071, 88.297423835906, 8.50554349658773, 
        3.5764241495006, 29.284865737912, 21.1213079519954, 2.3070166819956, 
        10.7659615128225, 33.4813413290485, 2.49896565066211, 59.0935696616465, 
        13.2863515051715, 4.36424795471221, 72.1627847396763, 9.09326343200557, 
        2.13701784901259, 27.5824079679471, 8.84486812842272, 1.98293342019671, 
        17.5321126287485, 19.1806349705231, 5.03952187899644, 58.3473975730234, 
        9.17287686145614, 2.99575072457674)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    105L))


df$man_ref_ <- relevel(df$treatment, "UN")
df$level_ref_ <- relevel(df$level, "L")

library(lme4)
model_lmer_C <- lmer ((continuous) ~  man_ref_ * level_ref_ + 
                             (1|random), data= df, REML = TRUE)
```

Most of the assumptions are not met. 
Assumption of linearity:

```
Linearity<-plot(resid(model_lmer_C),df$continuous)
```

[image]
Assumption of homoscedasticity:

```
df2 <- df
#extracts the residuals:
df2$model_lmer_C_Res <- 
        residuals(model_lmer_C) 
#absolute value of the residuals:
df2$Abs.model_lmer_C.Res <-
        abs(df2$model_lmer_C_Res)
#squares the absolute values:
df2$model_lmer_C.Res2 <- 
        df2$Abs.model_lmer_C.Res^2 
#ANOVA of the squared residuals:
Levene.model_lmer_C <- 
        lm(model_lmer_C.Res2 ~ treatment, data=df2)
#displays the results:
anova_levenemodel_lmer_C <- anova(Levene.model_lmer_C) 
plot(model_lmer_C)
```

While p>0.05, the plot does not look great:
[image]
[image]
Assumption normality of residuals:

```
require("lattice")
qqmath(model_lmer_C, id=0.05)
```

[image]

Comment: Generalized linear model (glm, glmer) is a different concept than nonparametric analysis....  If all the variables on the right side are factor (nominal) variables, then a nonparametric approach with aligned ranks transformation may be possible (http://depts.washington.edu/madlab/proj/art/).  Probably the advice on this site will be to start with what kind of data your dependent variable is, and then choose an appropriate glm or regression approach.  That is, if your dv is count, perhaps Poisson or negative binomial regression.  If your dv is concentration, perhaps gamma regression.

Comment: Thank you. What alternative model would you suggest (I need to account for `random`)? `df` contains two factor explanatory variables (`treatment` and `level`), the dependent continuous variable `continuous` and the random variable (`random`). Can I use `glmer` in this case? Would something like this work? `model_lmer_C <- glmer ((continuous) ~  man_ref_ * level_ref_ + 
                             (1|random), data= df, family=gamma)`

Comment: Based on your dv, gamma regression might make sense.  But I'm not going to comment on a specific model because I don't understand what it means that nearly half of your random variable is set to NA.

Comment: Yes, the random variable only applies to one of the two treatments. It's like you have two treatments (UN, CCF) and in one of the two (CCF) somebody had divided the treatment in four sub-treatments, then conducted an experiment which I am not interested in, but I want to account for in the model.

Comment: @SalMangiafico can you suggest any source of information where I can find solutions to adapt the model when the assumptions are not met? Thank you